# Is there a way to use DATE_FORMAT to SELECT multiple months?

Tags: mysql

[image]
From the above ERD I am trying to Select the total number of products sold and their descriptions in February, September, and December.

Here's a snippet of my invoice table:

```
INV_NUMBER CUS_CODE INV_DATE 

1001       10014    2016-01-16 00:00:00
1002       10011    2016-01-16 00:00:00
1003       10012    2016-01-16 00:00:00
```

My SQL query :

```
SELECT P_DESCRIPT AS Product, SUM(P_CODE) AS 'Units Sold'

FROM  product
JOIN invoice 
WHERE INV_DATE LIKE (DATE_FORMAT("2017-01%-15", "%Y", "%m" ) 
OR  DATE_FORMAT("2017-06%-15", "%Y", "%m" ) 
OR DATE_FORMAT("2017-07%-15", "%Y", "%m" ))

GROUP BY P_DESCRIPT;
```

I know that I got everything wrong from "WHERE ... %m" ))
I need to get something like this [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be simpler to write this using the [`YEAR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) and [`MONTH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month) functions (2, 9 and 12 representing February, September, and December):

```
SELECT p.P_DESCRIPT AS Product, SUM(p.P_CODE) AS 'Units Sold'
FROM product p
JOIN line l ON l.P_CODE = p.P_CODE
JOIN invoice i ON i.INV_NUMBER = l.INV_NUMBER
WHERE YEAR(i.INV_DATE) = 2017
  AND MONTH(i.INV_DATE) IN (2, 9, 12)
GROUP BY p.P_DESCRIPT
```

Comment: also need join criteria (which the question missed too)

Comment: @danblack indeed, I copied it from the question directly. Given there's a blank line in the question I suspect that was the missing JOIN. anyway I've added it now.

Comment: Ran your query in MySQL and couldn't get a column of the answer but rather a row

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté Sorry, I left out the `GROUP BY` when I copied the query from your question. See my edited version

Comment: @Nick I get an Error Code: 1052. Column 'P_CODE' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: I could PM you the database file if that can help.

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté I've added table aliases and qualified the column names. That should resolve the issue

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to use DATE_FORMAT in this query? I am curious as to why it wouldn't be possible. Thank for your answer!

Comment: @MahamadA.Kanouté you *could* use it, for example something like `DATE_FORMAT(i.INV_DATE, '%Y%m') IN ('201702', '201709', '201712')` but using `YEAR` and `MONTH` is much simpler and faster for this task.

Comment: Or keeping the values as dates so MySQL understands that this is 3 ranges which may optimize better (perhaps in the future) `WHERE ('20170201' <= i.INV_DATE and i.INV_DATE < '20170301') OR ('20170901' <= i.INV_DATE and i.INV_DATE < '20171001')  OR ('20171201' <= i.INV_DATE and i.INV_DATE < '20190101')`